# Regex for the following conditions

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex for the following scenario.

1. Regex allowed only number
2. Don't start and end with `-` (hypen)
3. In Whole Number it should contain only 0 or 2 `*` (asterisk)

Example:

```
*1,
1*,
1-1,
1*-*1,
*1-*1,
*1-1
1*-1,
1-*1,
1-1*,
1**,
1,
**1
**1-1
1**-1
1-**1,
1-1**,
1-*1*,
*1*-1,
1*11-*1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Requirement 3 conflicts with 1, and requirement 1 also conflicts with what is implied in 2. What code have you used that failed?

Comment: If it can only contain 0 or 2 asterisks, wouldn't that make half the strings invalid? Do you mean to say it should contain a maximum of 2 asterisks?

Comment: @ctwheels: you don't need a lookbehind. Change `[\d*-]*(?<!-)` to `(?:-[\d*]+)*`

Comment: For the first question you asked it can contain number and * and -  that's my bad

Comment: @ctwheels For the second question it should contain maximum of 2 *(asterisk)

Comment: @suresh I've removed my previous comment regex as I noticed a minor typo. Instead, I've posted an answer with various regular expressions you can use. I'm not sure which language/regex engine you're looking for. Most support lookaheads, but, for the few that don't, you should be able to use the long ugly one I posted. If that doesn't work replace `\d` with `0-9` inside the sets and `[0-9]` outside the sets.

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9D81qw/2). This method uses fewer steps - *360 steps* - (better performance) than anything else I could come up with (apart from expanding the first non capture group - see the first regex in the next section - *305 steps*).

```
^(?!(?:[^*\r\n]*\*){3})[\d*]+(?:-[\d*]+)?$
```

You can also use any of the following:

```
^(?![^*\r\n]*\*[^*\r\n]*\*[^*\r\n]*\*)[\d*]+(?:-[\d*]+)?$
^(?!-|(?:.*\*){3})[\d*-]*[\d*]$
^(?!-|(?:.*\*){3})[\d*-]+(?<!-)$
```

Without a lookahead you can use the following, but I warn you, it's super ugly:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9D81qw/3)

```
^(?:\d+(?:\*?[\d-]*\*?|[\d-]*\*{0,2}[\d-]*)\d+|(?:\d*|\d[\d-]*)\*[\d-]*\*(?:\d*|[\d-]*\d)|(?:\d*|\d[\d-]*)\*(?:\d*|[\d-]*\d)|\d+)$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
*1
1*
1-1
1*-*1
*1-*1
*1-1
1*-1
1-*1
1-1*
1**
1
**1
**1-1
1**-1
1-**1
1-1**
1-*1*
*1*-1
1*11-*1

-1*1
1*1*1*1
1-
```

#### Output

```
*1
1*
1-1
1*-*1
*1-*1
*1-1
1*-1
1-*1
1-1*
1**
1
**1
**1-1
1**-1
1-**1
1-1**
1-*1*
*1*-1
1*11-*1
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!(?:[^*\r\n]*\*){3})` Negative lookahead ensuring the string contains no more than 2 asterisks `*` (negates the string once a third one is found)
- `[\d*]+` Match a digit or asterisk character `*` one or more times
- `(?:-[\d*]+)?` Match the following zero or one time

  - `-` Match this literally
  - `[\d*]+` Match a digit or asterisk character `*` one or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?!([^\s*]*[*]){3})(?!-)^[0-9*-]*(?!.*-)[0-9*]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/opC5PB/1